# Shortest path in a graph in c without static vector

Tags: c, graph

i have a graph with a combination of bidirectional and unidirectional links, and i need to find the shortest path between two given nodes, and i can't use any static vector or matrix.

I also need to specify all the nodes in the path used.

This is the way i foundto create the graph, so each node has a pointer to the nodes he's connected, any ideas on how i can do this? i tried creating another structure that travel along all the pointers until it finds the given destiny, but that was just a mess.

```
struct cel {
    int rota1,rota2,rota3,rota4,rota5;
    struct cel *p1,*p2,*p3,*p4,*p5;
};

typedef struct cel celula;

    celula* newnode(struct cel *p1,struct cel*p2,struct cel*p3,struct cel*p4,struct cel*p5, int rota1,int rota2,int rota3,int rota4,int rota5){
    celula* new,*aux;

    new= (celula *) malloc( sizeof( celula ));
    if(new== NULL)
    printf("Erro!");
    new->p1=p1;
    new->p2=p2;
    new->p3=p3;
    new->p4=p4;
    new->p5=p5;
    new->rota1,rota2,rota3,rota4,rota5=0;
    aux = new;
    return (aux);
}

celula * UTFPR;
celula * JAPAO;
celula * REIDOPAO;
celula * ESTACAO;

UTFPR = newnode(REIDOPAO,JAPAO,ESTACAO,NULL,NULL,1,2,1,0,0);
REIDOPAO = newnode(JAPAO,UTFPR,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,1,0,0,0);
JAPAO = newnode(ESTACAO,UTFPR,REIDOPAO,NULL,NULL,2,2,2,0,0);
ESTACAO = newnode(UTFPR,JAPAO,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,2,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` (e.g. returned by `malloc()`) to/from other pointers! Note: you should not use `new`. If you ever compile that code with a C++ compiler, it will yield errors.

Comment: @Olaf: On the one hand I agree with both statements on, on the other hand I can't but notice that they contradict each other.

Comment: @MikeMB: Now as I read your comment, I noticed:-). You are absolutely right! However, adding the cast lateron might cause much less trouble than finding the error with `new` as an identifier. The latter might also confuse syntax-highlighting, as we see here on SO (notice the color for `new`). And I think there is no harm done if using a different identifier, wheras casting malloc can very well be.

Comment: @Olaft: I completely agree.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Dijkstra's algorithm.  You can find an explanation and pseudo code here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: well, the thing is that Dijkstra's algorithm uses vectors, i'm having a hard time to make these without any. thanks anyway

Comment: The code I linked is pseudo code - you can implement it using whatever data structure you wish.  All you need is a way to store a value with a certain index, and later retrieve that value from the index.  The algorithm does not change according to how the data is stored.  You can make it completely abstract by specifying a setValue( index, value ) and a getValue( index ), then implementing these using whatever you prefer.